# Primefaces dialog with modal=true not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces

I am unable to achieve a (primefaces)`dialog` box with attribute `modal=true`. It works correctly with modal=false, but when I try to set `modal=true`, even the dialog box overlay becomes inactive.

How can I make it work properly ?

Comment: This isn't very much information, did you try setting the attribute `appendToBody=true`?  Try posting your code.

Comment: Thanks this works now, after setting `appendToBody="true"` !

Comment: Is there any easier way to manipulate the opacity of the overlayed section ? You may consider posting this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607921/primefaces-dialog-appendtobody-true-not-working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the Primefaces Guide 2.2 on the Dialog section:

> appendToBody FALSE Boolean Appends dialog as a child of document body.

When using the Primefaces dialog utilize the appendToBody attribute to enable the dialog overlay to be found.  The Primefaces dialog is based on the YUI dialog component which has a similar issue for modal dialog overlays.

Manipulating the dialog overlay will involve overriding the CSS class of the overlay and specifying your own opacity.

Answer (score 20):

With Primefaces 5 `appendTo="@(body)"` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I was having trouble when using RequestContext#execute("PF('widgetvar').hide()"), my dialog was hiding as expected but the translucent overlay wouldn't. Code worked fine with PF 5.1 but broke with 5.2/5.3. This solution made things work well again (missed something in the docs for sure...).

Comment: I'm sure this would work, however in my situation, my dialog is inside a form (and I have form fields inside the dialog), so I cant afford to move the dialog out to the body, without re-arranging my whole xhml. will continue looking for a solution, having upgraded from PF 4 to PF 5.3

Comment: @hendinas I fixed with appendTo="myForm" (where `myForm` is the id of the containing form). Apparently this was enough to move the dialog at the end of the form DOM instead of it being inside a `form`+`tabView`+`panelGrid` hierarchy which apparently broke the overlay handling of my `confirmDialog` upgrading from PF 7.0 to 8.0...

Answer (score 9):

I have also struggled with strange behaviour until I moved the `p:dialog` into a separate `h:form` at which point the data in the dialog matched the row from the dataTable but the overlay was not hiding.

`appendToBody=true` solved the problem with the overlay. I still need to test dialogs with inputs and actions.

Answer (score 3):

appendToBody=true causes the problems associated with nested forms - the input texts values as entered at the dialog are ignore and ajax requests do not go through until the dialog gets its own non-nested form. Even without modal=true the appentToBody=true causes this behavior.

Comment: Interestingly enough this is still the case, 5 or 6 years later.. You'd think they figured out a fix by now.