# Modality not removed from underlying window in p:confirmDialog

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog

I'm using a PrimeFaces "global" `<p:confirmDialog>` and using the p:Confirm tag to call it for commandButton press with PrimeFaces version 5

When "yes" or "no" is pressed on the confirm dialog, the dialog disappears, but the underlying panel is not active (i.e. the modality is not turned off). The action is being successfully concluded on the server though (on "yes"), and the data is properly updated - the only issue is that the panel isn't active.

Here is my relevant code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" 
    xmlns:cust="http://memarden.com">

<link href="CSS/navigation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h:body>
    <h3>#{text['organization']}</h3>
    <ui:composition template="template-restricted.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="body_content">
            <h:form id="mainForm">
                <div id="title" class="sl-title">Manage Schools - #{manageOrgHierarchy.selectedOrganization.displayString}</div>
                <div class="sr-content">
                <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive"><div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4"><p:panel layout="block">
                <p:toolbar><f:facet name="left">
                    <p:commandButton  
                        title="New Root Org"
                        icon="fa fa-folder-open" 
                        rendered="#{userSession.isAdmin}"
                        process="@form"
                        update="@form"
                        action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.createNewRootOrg}" />
                    <p:commandButton      
                        title="#{text['new.item']}"
                        icon="fa fa-folder-open" 
                        process="@form"
                        update="@form"
                        action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.createNewSubOrg}" />
                    <p:commandButton      
                        title="#{text['delete']}"
                        icon="fa fa-trash"
                        process="@form"
                        update="@form"
                        disabled="#{not manageOrgHierarchy.canBeDeleted}"
                        action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.delete}" />
                    <p:commandButton      
                        title="#{text['save']}"
                        icon="fa fa-save" 
                        process="@form"
                        update="@form"
                        action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.save}" />
                </f:facet></p:toolbar>
                <p:tree
                        id="orgTree"
                        value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.rootNodes}"
                        selectionMode="single"
                        selection="#{manageOrgHierarchy.selectedNode}"
                        style="ui-grid-col-2"
                        var="node">
                    <p:ajax event="select" update="mainForm" listener="#{manageOrgHierarchy.nodeSelected}" />
                    <p:ajax event="unselect" update="mainForm" listener="#{manageOrgHierarchy.nodeUnselected}" />
                    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{manageOrgHierarchy.nodeExpanded}" />
                    <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{manageOrgHierarchy.nodeCollapsed}" />
                    <p:treeNode type="OrganizationHierarchy">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node.nickName}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree></p:panel>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-8">
            <p:tabView>
                <p:tab id="userTab" title="#{text['users']}">
                    <p:commandButton
                        id="addUserButton"
                        value="#{text['addUser']}"
                        icon="fa fa-user"
                        process="userTab"
                        update="userTab"
                        type="button" />
                    <p:overlayPanel
                        id="addUserPanel"
                        for="addUserButton"
                        dynamic="false" >
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <p:inputText id="userSearch" value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.searchUser.searchKey}" />
                            <p:commandButton      
                                title="#{text['search']}"
                                icon="fa fa-search"
                                process="@form"
                                update="@form"
                                action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.searchUser.update}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:dataList
                            value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.searchUser.results}"
                            var="user"
                            type="definition" 
                            paginator="true" 
                            rows="10" 
                            styleClass="paginated">
                            <p:commandLink 
                                title="#{text['select']}"
                                process="@form"
                                update="@form"
                                action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.addUser(user)}"
                                styleClass="fa fa-check"/>
                            <h:outputText value=" #{text['name']}: #{user.nickName} ; #{text['username']}: #{user.name}" />
                        </p:dataList>
                    </p:overlayPanel>
                    <p:accordionPanel id="userDisplayPanel" value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.userPermissions}" var="p">
                    <p:tab title="#{p.user.displayString}">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-4,ui-grid-col-8">
                        <div class="userIcon.img"><cust:avatarOutput owner="#{p.user}" session="#{userSession}" /></div>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputText value="#{text['name']}: " /><h:outputText value="#{p.user.displayString}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{text['username']}: " /><h:outputText value="#{p.user.name}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{text['admin']}" /><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{p.userManagementPermissions}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{text['teacher']}" /><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{p.instructorPermissions}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{text['observer']}" /><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{p.observerPermissions}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton      
                        title="#{text['save']}"
                        icon="fa fa-save" 
                        process="@form"
                        update="@form"
                        action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.saveUserPermissions(p)}" />
                    <p:commandButton      
                        title="#{text['delete']}"
                        icon="fa fa-trash"
                        process="@form"
                        update="@form"
                        action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.deleteUserPermissions(p)}" >
                        <p:confirm 
                            header="#{text['confirm']}" 
                            message="#{text['confirm.sure']}" 
                            icon="fa fa-alert" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    </p:tab>
                    </p:accordionPanel>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="#{text['profile']}">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid">
                        <p:outputLabel for="name" value="#{text['name']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.editOrg.nickName}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid">
                        <p:outputLabel for="phone" value="#{text['phone']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="phone" value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.editOrg.phone}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid">
                        <p:outputLabel for="address" value="#{text['address']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="address" value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.editOrg.address}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid">
                        <p:outputLabel for="city" value="#{text['city']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="city" value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.editOrg.city}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid">
                        <p:outputLabel for="state" value="#{text['state']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="state" value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.editOrg.state}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid">
                        <p:outputLabel for="postalCode" value="#{text['post.code']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="postalCode" value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.editOrg.postalCode}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid">
                        <p:outputLabel for="country" value="#{text['address.country']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="country" value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.editOrg.country}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton      
                        value="#{text['cancel']}"
                        icon="fa fa-trash"
                        process="@form"
                        update="@form"
                        action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.cancelEditOrg}" />
                    <p:commandButton      
                        value="#{text['save']}"
                        icon="fa fa-save" 
                        process="@form"
                        update="@form"
                        action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.saveEditOrg}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="#{text['lessons']}"></p:tab>
                <p:tab title="#{text['reports']}"></p:tab>
            </p:tabView></div></div></div>
            </div>
          </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>

<p:confirmDialog
    global="true" 
    showEffect="fade"
    hideEffect="fade" >
    <p:commandButton
      value="Yes" 
      type="button" 
      styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
      icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton
      value="No" 
      type="button" 
      styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
      icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Is this really the most minimalistic code that shows the problem? If not, please make it more minimalistic, remove as much as possible. And also post a minimalistic bean if it plays a role. And how is the confirmDialog related to the other xhtml code? It is outside the `<html>` tag. And please post version info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `appendTo="@(body)"`worked for me. I was trying `appendToBody="true"`, which does not work in PrimeFaces 5 as described here [in the Primefaces migration guide](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide)

This was also mentioned in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410426/primefaces-dialog-with-modal-true-not-working-properly) as the third answer down - I missed it at first, and remembered it later.